# jQuery returning "undefined" css display

Tags: jquery, firefox, css

I have a page that has a few divs on it with their default display style (set in external .css file `#somediv{display:none`).  If a condition is met, i use jQuery to turn one on, and the others off.  I use jQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` methods to control this.

In FF18 only, there seem to random instances when the `fadeIn` does not work.  I put an alert in the js file

```
alert($("#someDiv").css("display"));
```

on the times the `fadeIn` does not seem to work, this alert outputs "undefined" as a value.  What would cause that, shouldnt jQuery at least return an empty string?

To add detail, in regards to Joseph's comment.  The jQuery object returned from the selector is correct and if I re-write my fadeIn() to this:

```
 $("#someDiv").fadeIn(400, function(){ $("#someDiv").css("display", "block")  });
```

It works 100% of the time.

Comment: jQuery returns undefined if you call `.css()` on an empty collection. Are you sure your selector matches the elements in question? Try `console.log( $("#someDiv") )`. Does the collection actually have any elements in it?

Comment: it does, I checked that, and the jQuery object returned has a length of 1, and the 0 index object is the correctly selected html element.

Answer (score 0):

You said you use this rule to control more than one div element, yet I see you're using ID# with the same property as selector, you can't have more than one element in a page with the same id. try switching it to a class selector and it might help.